# Why volume goes up automatically on my iPhone 6s when I'm running on a treadmill?

Tags: iphone, audio

When I'm running on a treadmill the volume goes up automatically while I'm watching Netflix or listening to Spotify.

It seems to go up one bar at the time, with about 1 second pause in between the increments. There's nothing pressing the volume buttons as phone is lying flat on the treadmill panel. It seems to stop when I'm running slower or walking.

I have a pair of wired Senzer H2 Earphones connected to my iPhone 6s.

What could be causing this interference? And why it's going up but never down?

Comment: First thing I’d try is whether it happens with the headphones unplugged, everything else the same.

Comment: Will try today without the headphones and will post back